# How to use jQuery Mobile selectmenu custom style with $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

We are developing a mobile app using PhoneGap and Backbone.js.  In order to enable Backbone's router to handle hashtag changes, all tutorials tell you to set the following property:

```
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
```

While this works great to enable Backbone, it is now causing a bug with the selectmenu.  Specifically, we want to use the custom style of selectmenu popup (as opposed to native), but it doesn't work with that option set to false.

[image: custom style menu]

I'm looking for a way to manually intercept this event and show the custom menu.  The first thing I thought of is to manually capture the click and use the selectmenu's "open" method, but this doesn't work.

I've created a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/zPS5j/) to demonstrate the problem.  When you first load it up, you can click on the selectmenu and it will open the custom-style menu. If you toggle the linkBindingEnabled to false, it no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we seem to have found a workaround.  Previously, I had tried to use the open method of the selectmenu, like:

```
$("#selectId").selectmenu("open");
```

But this didn't work, probably because it was still relying on jQM's click handling.  It turns out that when the page is rendered, jQM creates the custom menus for each selectmenu and hides them off-screen, giving them an ID in the form of *#selectId-listbox*.  You can use the [popup widget](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/widgets/popup/) to then show this menu programmatically.

```
$("#selectId-listbox").popup("open");
```

Unfortunately, since we now have to handle all click handling duties, you must manually capture the user's selection, update the underlying form element and close the menu.

Comment: Hi! Can you share your workout? I cant get it working with popup function. Tried to search inside jqeryMobile lib, too hard to understand there (

Comment: Hey, I've updated the Fiddle to illustrate the solution better.  Let me know if you can get it working.  http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/8WxHx/

Comment: In your fiddle the popup apperas in center of screen. Did you managed to fix it? And what functions did you called for "manually capture the user's selection, update the underlying form element and close the menu"?

Comment: What do you mean by fix it?  I believe that's the normal behavior of jQM.  As you can see, I didn't add any CSS or other customizations.  That's out-of-the-box functionality.  And I don't think my previous statement that you had to manually capture the selection is correct.  As you can see from the Fiddle, just click on a value and the select is updated.

Comment: here is default behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/f9Pt2/ it appears near control that created it

Comment: That's the default behavior of the custom select menu.  Remember, we're disabling it and using the popup functionality to show the menu.  I suppose you could customize it somehow but in our case, we used it in a mobile app and a centered view was appropriate.  So no, we didn't change it.

Comment: I dunno.  Maybe there's a way but that's not the solution I found, sorry.  If you find another way please update me, I'd like to know.

Comment: i have a    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {}) where i set linkBindingEnabled as you do. The answer of Gajotres tells to move $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false; before including jquery-mobile.js, mb we should move this init somehow earlier?

Comment: If you set that option in `$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {})` then that is the correct way.  I disagree with Gajotres when he thinks that it is a configuration issue.  The root issue is that jQM uses hashes to show the custom menu.  If you look at the code, it creates a link on the custom select like `<a href="#select1-listbox"...>` and it intercepts that hash and interprets it to mean "please open the menu slect1-listbox".  When you set `$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false`, this will disable jQM's handling of hashes.

Answer (score 1):

First, your example is not working correctly. I am not going to talk about backbone problematic, instead I will try to explain to you what is wrong with your example and how is that going to cause problems with jQuery.

**linkBindingEnabled**  is a part of jQuery Mobile initialization setting and it must be initialized before jQuery Mobile, something like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Read more about it here: [**Working with jQuery Mobile's Auto-initialization**](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html).

When properly initialized it doesnt matter if **linkBindingEnabled** is **true** or **false**.

Here's a correct working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JJ3Ds/

Now you can use this information to fix your project problem. If you are using require.js to handle initializations you can create new js file, put everything inside (with mobileinit) and initialize it before jquery mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the info about proper initialization of configurable options.  However, you're getting too hung up on the fiddle (which, by the way, does in fact demonstrate the behavior I am referring to for whatever unknown reason).

Our actual code does set auto-initialization on the "mobileinit" event.  If I take the $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false; statement out of there, the custom select menu is no longer broken.  So I believe my original conclusion that it's causing the problem is still valid and therefore I still need a workaround to this.

Comment: The only reason this Fiddle works is because you are not surrounding `$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;` with `$(document).on("mobileinit"...`.  Because you are not disabling jQM's routing, it will not work with Backbone, like the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

gabrielschulhof gave a sample here:

http://jsbin.com/sacota/4/

See also:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7961